# is it wrong to treat panic / recover as throw / catch

Tags: go

Speaking as a new go enthusiast trying to work with the go way of error handling. To be clear - I like exceptions.

I have a server that accepts a connection , processes a set of requests and replies to them. I found that I can do

```
if err != nil{
      panic(err)
}
```

in the deep down processing code

and have

```
defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("%s: %s", err, debug.Stack()) // line 20
        }
    }()
```

in the client connection code (each connection is in a goroutine). This nicely wraps everything up, forcefully closes the connection (other defers fire) and my server continues to hum along.

But this feels an awful lot like a throw/catch scenario - which golang states it doesn't support. Questions

- is this stable. ie recovering a panic is an OK thing to do as an
  ongoing way of life. Its not intended to just slightly defer an
  immediate shutdown
- I looked for a discussion on this topic and did not find it anywhere   - any pointers?

I feel that the answer is 'yes it works' and can be used inside you own code, but panic should NOT be used by a library intended for wider use. The standard and polite way for a library to behave is by error returns

Comment: Just so you know, `debug.Stack` is deprecated. Use `runtime.Stack` with a really big buffer instead.

Comment: It would really be nice to develop in Go using the **Exception** paradigm instead of doing *if-check* on every single line of code (potentially, every command can fail).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you suggest. There are some situations within the standard packages where panic/recover is used for handling errors. The [official Go blog](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) states:

> For a real-world example of **panic** and **recover**, see the json package
>   from the Go standard library. It decodes JSON-encoded data with a set
>   of recursive functions. When malformed JSON is encountered, the parser
>   calls panic to unwind the stack to the top-level function call, which
>   recovers from the panic and returns an appropriate error value (see
>   the 'error' and 'unmarshal' methods of the decodeState type in
>   decode.go).

Some pointers:

- Use `error` for your normal use cases. This should be your default.
- If your code would get clearer and simpler by using a `panic`/`recover` (such as with a recursive call stack), then use it for that particular case.
- Never let a package leak panics. Panics used within a package should be recovered within the package and returned as an error.
- Recovering from a panic is stable. Don't worry about continuing execution after a recover. You can see such behavior in standard library such as with the `net/http` package which recovers from panics within handlers to prevent the entire http server to go crash when panicing on a single request.

Comment: I'd say one exception is math packages. The tradeoff of error values is that you can no longer use math functions in forumulas, sometimes it makes sense to panic on "can't happen" input in favor of method chaining. Generally "can't happen" inputs in math packages are a sign of an unrecoverable state anyway. (The cases where it panics should be clearly documented, of course).

Comment: "The convention in the Go libraries is that even when a package uses panic internally, its external API still presents explicit error return values." - [golang blog](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover). I think I saw some built in modules/libraries that break this convention. For example, array index out of range is a panic.

Comment: I find Go has too much error verbosity. A lot of errors are unexpected execution conditions, and for much of those I simply panic to log it and escape the request.

Answer (score 1):

Generally most methods won't panic, they will return an error instead, and there's a bit of an overhead of using defer.

So yes, it does work, but the "proper" / "go" way is to return an error instead of using panic / recover.